# Fresco image loader controller

Tags: android, fresco

I'm using Fresco image loading library and my question is can I use it like this inside an adapter? and by that I mean calling the controller every time the bindView gets called, there doesn't seem to be an issue with it and it's not really described [here](http://frescolib.org/docs/animations.html)

```
        public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
            .setOldController(imageview.getController())
            .setUri(Uri.parse("file://" + sdPath))
            .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
            .build();
            imageview.setController(controller);
        }
```

And the second question is that I'm using the above for the GIF images but it's working fine with images as well, so can I use the above for both? or should I use the above for GIF only and the following for images,

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Uri.parse("file://" + sdPath));
SimpleDraweeView imageview = (SimpleDraweeView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
imageview.setImageURI(uri);
```

The reason I'm asking this is because in universal image loader I call the instance once like so, and then use it in the bindView as it's the recommended way of using it in an Adapter.

```
private static class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
        private ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

        public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
           imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + sdPath, imageview);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is completely safe to use the first approach both for animations and static images. In fact, `setImageURI` gets translated to exactly the same thing except for `setAutoPlayAnimations` which is false by default. `setAutoPlayAnimations` gets ignored for static images so it doesn't hurt to have it always true.